# Получить путь к USB флешке и прочитать файлы

Tags: java, android, android-studio, usb

Всем привет! Моя цель: при подключении флешки проверить, есть ли файл с определённым именем на ней.

BroadcastReceiver:

```
private final String TAG = "USBDevicesReceiver";
UsbManager manager;
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    try{
        Log.d(TAG, intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)){
            try {
                manager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (manager != null){
                HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
                for (final UsbDevice device : deviceList.values()) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "start request");
                        String path = device.getDeviceName();
                        Log.d(TAG, path);
                        if (FindFile.isFileFound(path, "log.txt")) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Its NULL");
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Метод которым я ищу файл:

```
public static boolean isFileFound(String path, String fileName) {
    File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();

    Log.d("Files", String.valueOf(files.length));
    if (files.length != 0){
        for (File file : files){
            if (file.isFile()){
                Log.d("FILENAME", file.getName());
                if (file.getName().equals(fileName)) return true;
            } else if (file.isDirectory()){
                isFileFound(file.getPath(), fileName);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
```

Мне приходит путь в Receiver'e: /dev/bus/usb/001/002

Но на этом методе: `File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();`
files == null

Что я делаю не так и как это сделать правильно?

Comment: а на доступ к файловой системе права есть?

Comment: @JVic READ\WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - есть. И в рантайме запрашиваю тоже (но при запуске аппы, так что тут кода этого нет)

Comment: Как уже говорил, думаю, что `device.getDeviceName` возвращает не путь в файловой системе. Девайс может быть вообще не хранилищем, а name у него будет.

Comment: @Miha_x64 Цитата из [доков](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html):
_Returns the name of the device. In the standard implementation, this is the path of the device file for the device in the usbfs file system._

Comment: Только писатель доков не утрудился объяснить, [что такое usbfs](http://www.linux-usb.org/USB-guide/x173.html).

Comment: @Miha_x64 получается, только на rooted телефонах это сработает?
> To mount the filesystem, you need to be root.

Comment: В Linux все устройства представляются в виде файловой системы. Сокеты, каналы связи, USB-устройства — всё это выглядит, как файлы, но работает иначе. Так что USBFS — это о другом. У любого подключённого USB-устройства будет адрес в USBFS, но это вовсе не значит, что это флешка — это может быть мышь, микрофон, что угодно.